# ChartJS line chart x = y not rendering astraight line

Tags: chart.js

I need to render some line that has many points (200) and at the beginning x equals y.

But as you can see on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Pachoulie/pen/MmVEdV), the line is not straight.
Is there a way to have a smooth rendering ?

Thank you very much

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

function generateFakeData() {
  var res = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
    res.push(i);
  }

  return res;
}
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: generateFakeData(),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "# of Votes",
        data: generateFakeData(),
        radius: 0,
        borderColor: "#156FB4"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I ended up displaying only the first and last points of the straight line...

Comment: I went with only adding points where the gradient changes. Looks good enough but it would have been nice to plot every point.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to change your fake data function to be:

```
function generateFakeData() {
  var res = [];
  res[0] = 0;
  res[200] = 200;
  return res;
}
```

and add `spanGaps: true` to the options, the line will be nice and straight, otherwise the way the pixels line up will make it look jagged as it tries to connect each one.

Not sure if this helps with your use case.